# SQL, give database records value and check if they exists

Tags: sql, oracle, crystal-reports

I need to create a formula in Crystal Reports for calculating a summary.
I need to give a value for every record in database table ENV_REG. Unfortunately i can not edit database by adding a new "value-field".
After giving values for every record i need to check if these records exists in another table and if yes, then calculate the summary of existing records values.

```
  Count=0;
  If exists (select*from table where ENV_REG=H220) then count+20
  Else do nothing
  If exists (select*from table where ENV_REG=H210) then count+30
  Else do nothing
  If exists (select*from table where ENV_REG=H211) then count+30
  Else do nothing
  …Ando so on….
  Display count
```

Iàm thinking about something like this.. Please help me out if possible and dont be rude.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverload! Can you please show us what you've attempted so far, as well as some table design so we know what we're working with?

Comment: 1) Which sql are you using, add a tag 2) What do you mean "summary"? Maybe "sum", ie 1+2+3=6?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

For mysql
you can use variable  below way

```
SET @H200 = 10, @H220 = 50;    

SELECT @H200,@H220
```